# How to list all downloaded android apps in a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app similar to [Action Launcher](http://www.actionlauncher.com/), but I am hitting some bumps in the road. I can't seem to get the installed apps to populate in a fragment.

It either crashes or it just doesn't populate with the apps (the view of the apps). I currently have it set up to load all apps into an ArrayList/List, that has 90 apps installed so that I'm not worried about. It's displaying the actual apps that I am having the hardest time with. I am trying to do this dynamically, and it's not working the way I want it to.

```
/* 
 * Assume that 
 * GridView gv;
 * Config cnf = new Config(); //personal class
 * PackageManager pm;
 * pm = getPackageManager();
 * 
 */
public void SelectItem(int possition) {
 switch(possition){
   case 2:
    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    // ArrayList<Apps> apps = cnf.getApps();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(returnContext());

    gl.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (ResolveInfo appInfo : apps) {
       String label = (String) appInfo.loadLabel(pm);
       TextView name2 = new TextView(returnContext());
       name2.setText(label);
       gl.addView(name2);
       ImageView img = new ImageView(returnContext());
       img.setImageDrawable(appInfo.loadIcon(pm));
       gl.addView(img);
    }
    gv.addView(gl); // I am getting a null reference exception here
  }
}
```

And the Base XML for the above code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appicon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/apptitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am assuming that my issue lies with the obvious (I am not setting a value properly.) and not the bigger issue of I don't know what I am doing and I messed something up (which I don't and probably did)

I uploaded my source to [GitHub](https://github.com/austinkregel/CustomAndroidLauncher) :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since absolutely no one came even with a simple suggestion, I figured it out myself like a good little programmer.

This solution will list out all of the installed apps, with the inclusion of all apps with the `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, without including all of the system apps. I will admit it is slow to populate but the end solution is to actually use a database to help aid in loading all of the items.

`Since I have released this solution on` [github](https://github.com/austinkregel/AndroidLauncher) `I have these licensed under the` [MIT licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).
So the following is the solution.

```
public List<Apps> listAllApps() {
    List<Apps> apps = new ArrayList<Apps>();
    List<ApplicationInfo> appinfo = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    Apps app;
    i = 0;
    List<String> appnames = appNames();
    for (int j = 0; j < appinfo.size(); j++) {
        if (Config.in_array(appnames, appinfo.get(j).packageName)) {
            app = new Apps();
            app.setPackageName(appinfo.get(j).packageName);
            app.setTitle(appinfo.get(j).loadLabel(pm).toString());
            apps.add(app);
            if (appinfo.get(j).packageName.contains("gallery") ||
                appinfo.get(j).loadLabel(pm).toString().contains("gallery")) {
                    if (appinfo.get(j).name.contains("gallery")) {
                        setGalleryPackage(i, appinfo.get(j).packageName);
                    } else
                        setGalleryPackage(i, appinfo.get(j).packageName);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return apps;
    }

    public List appNames() {
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> packs = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<String>(packs.size());
        for (ResolveInfo ai : packs) {
            appNames.add(ai.activityInfo.packageName.toString());
        }
        return appNames;
    }
```

To actually add the items to the screen I had to put the following inside the (fragment) `onCreateView` method

```
List<Apps> loadedApps = listAllApps();
    Collections.sort(loadedApps, new Comparator<Apps>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Apps lhs, Apps rhs) {
            return lhs.getTitle().compareTo(rhs.getTitle());
        }
    });
    // Config.makeColdToast(loadedApps.size());

    for (final Apps a : loadedApps) {
        final TableRow tb = new TableRow(Config.context);
        tb.setId(i + 1000);
        Drawable ico = null;
        try {
            Intent in = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(a.getPackageName());
            if (in != null) {
                ico = pm.getActivityIcon(in);

            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        ImageView ima = new ImageView(Config.context);
        ima.setImageDrawable(ico);
        tb.addView(ima, new TableRow.LayoutParams(Config.dpToPx(50), Config.dpToPx(50)));
        TextView name = new TextView(Config.context);
        name.setText(a.getTitle());
        a.setID(i);
        tb.setPadding(Config.dpToPx(25), Config.dpToPx(10), Config.dpToPx(15), Config.dpToPx(10));
        tb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0));
        tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Config.context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(a.getPackageName());

                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                tb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }

        });
        tb.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                Config.makeColdToast("Long click!");

                return false;
            }
        });
        tb.addView(name, new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        gv.addView(tb, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        /*
         * This is the gray line...
         */
        TableRow tl = new TableRow(Config.context);
        tl.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.customborder);
        gv.addView(tl);
        i++;
    }
```

And finally the Apps class that is referenced several times.

```
public class Apps {

    private String title;
    private String packageName;
    private String versionName;
    private int versionCode;
    private String description;
    private ResolveInfo resolveinfo;
    Intent intent;

    private int id;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setResolveInfo(ResolveInfo ri) {
        this.resolveinfo = ri;
    }

    public ResolveInfo getResolveInfo() {
        return this.resolveinfo;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
            return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public int getVersionCode() {
            return versionCode;
    }

    public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public class AppViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle;
        public ImageView mIcon;


        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle.setText(title);
        }

        public void setIcon(Drawable img) {
            if (img != null) {
                    mIcon.setImageDrawable(img);
            }
        }
    }

    public Drawable mIcon;

    public void setIcons(Drawable icon) {
        mIcon = icon;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return mIcon;
    }
}
```