# Using a fragment to display user installed apps

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In the android app I am creating, I have a scrollable tabs from my TabsPagerAdapter class which extends FragmentPagerAdapter. However, in my app, I am trying to display all user installed apps on the phone into a section of a tab. However the class which was able to return all of that extended FragmentActivity.

I tried to follow this, but it is not working.

[How to list all downloaded android apps in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482981/how-to-list-all-downloaded-android-apps-in-a-fragment)

Sadly, after much research I found out that I can only put fragments in different tabs and only have one Activity displayed at any one time and the tabs themselves can only return Fragments.

I really need to put all the user installed apps into a Fragment in this case I guess but I am unsure how to implement this...I have an Adapter class and everything.

Here is my InstalledAppActivity class which extends FragmentActivity to return all user downloaded apps.

```
    package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.javatechig.listapps.ApplicationAdapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class InstalledAppActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private PackageManager packageManager = null;
        private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
        private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

        ListView InstalledAppList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.installed_apps);

            InstalledAppList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Installed_List);
            packageManager = getPackageManager();
            new LoadApplications().execute();

            InstalledAppList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(i);
                    try {
                        Intent intent = packageManager
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                        if (null != intent) {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }





        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            packageManager = getPackageManager();
            new LoadApplications().execute();
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, container, false);


        }


        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);

            return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            boolean result = true;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.main_text: {
                    displayAboutDialog();

                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void displayAboutDialog() {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.slogan));


            builder.setPositiveButton("Know More", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://javatechig.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No Thanks!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
  private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener OnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView InstalledAppList, View v, int position, long id) {
                ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
                try {
                    Intent intent = packageManager
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                    if (null != intent) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        };    
        private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
            ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
            for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
                try {
                    if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                        applist.add(info);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return applist;
        }

        private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog progress = null;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(InstalledAppActivity.this,
                        R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                //setListAdapter(listadaptor);
                InstalledAppList.setAdapter(listadaptor);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }



            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would do it:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {


//hi



    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();


        /*To filter out System apps*/

        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);

        new LoadApplications(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage1(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) ? false
                : true;
    }


// Don't need in Fragment
/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
   // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //ApkAdapter apkAdapter=(ApkAdapter)apkList.getAdapter();

    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Context mContext;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        public LoadApplications(Context context){
            Context mContext = context;
        }




        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);


          /*  List<ApplicationInfo> list = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);


            for(int n = 0;n<list.size();n++){
                if ((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP))
            }*/


            for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
                boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
                boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

                if(!b || !c ) {
                    packageList1.add(pi);
                }
            }

            //sort by application name

            final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

            Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
                    return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
                }
            });



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InstalledAppActivity.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading your apps...");
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

            if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

way don't you just from youre main activity on click off the tab create a fragment with a listview in it and displays the data list there?? you can pars the list to the fragment bay saying

```
fragmentclass fragment = new fragmentclass(list);
```

> fragment.show();

if youre having truble understanding fragments you can watch this [great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U) on it especialy the part on inter fragment communication is realy use full